# How to generate n number of ones in java?

Tags: java, algorithm, math, biginteger

I am stuck with an algorithm where i need to generate n number of figures '1', where `n<=10^16` and `n>=1` . I successfully generated n number of ones in a `for loop` with `BigInteger` because `long` as well as `string` are failed to hold this. But the problem is the time limit of this is `4 sec` and it takes more than `4 sec` for `n>10^5`. This is clearly generating in `O(n)`. I think corresponding code is not necessary. I find many websites but can not find any solution. Any better algorithm would be helpful. Thanks.

EDIT: it is a puzzle question where `n` and `m` are input and i need to print `111...(n times) mod m` where limits are `1≤N≤10^16` and `2≤M≤10^9`. For example,
Suppose `n=3` & `m=3` then print `111%3` which is equal to `0`
 Suppose `n=5` & `m=18` then print `11111%18` which is equal to `5`.
If you use `long` or `String` then a `NumberFormatException` is thrown then i change it to `BigInteger` then exception is gone.

```
public static void main(String[] ar){
    Scanner in= new Scanner(System.in);
    int t=in.nextInt();
    while(t-->0){
        BigInteger n=new BigInteger(Long.toString(in.nextLong()));
        BigInteger m=new BigInteger(Long.toString(in.nextLong()));
        BigInteger s=new BigInteger("1");
        for(long i=1;i<n.intValue();i++)
            s = s.multiply(new BigInteger("10")).add(new BigInteger("1"));
        System.out.println(s.mod(m));
}
```

[image]

Comment: So you need to generate a BigInteger on the form `11111..111` there the number of ones can be as large as 10^16?

Comment: Are we talking about binary numbers?

Comment: it is a puzzle question where n and m is input and i need to print 11..(n times) mod m

Comment: for storing n '1's in an array, you need to access 'n' memory addresses which mean it must take O(n) anyway. creating a integer 0xFFFF... and converting it into binary might seem a viable option but it still almost takes the same time. Can you tell me what exactly you are going to do with such an array? If every element is 1 then aren't you better off having just one '1' ??

Comment: I have post the exact question...

Comment: Constructing a number the length of the binary representation of which is n will always take time O(n) in any format which doesn't make explicit use of underlying structure (i.e. the fact that the number is 2^(10^n)). You won't be able to hold a number that big in memory. I expect that you need to find some mathematical way of reducing the problem to something with smaller numbers. The brute-force approach is effectively intractable.

Comment: This question is set by a by a person who is the master in math but i cant find the way out..

Comment: Suppose n=3 and m=3 then print 111%3

Comment: The point of questions such as "compute some ridiculously huge number,  give the result mod something" is to make you find a way to avoid doing it exactly as stated, they'll make sure the number is too huge to even think about handling it.

Comment: do you mind if I post full code/solution?

Comment: it will be a great help...thanks @Arvy..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If S(n) is n ones, then these equations hold:

```
S(1) = 1
S(2n) = S(n) * (10^n + 1)
S(n+1) = S(n) * 10 + 1
```

You can use these two recurrences (modulo m) to compute S(n) modulo m.

```
S(n) % m =
   1                                          [if n is 1]
   ((S(n/2) % m) * ((10^{n/2} % m) + 1)) % m  [if n is even]
   ((S(n-1) % m)) * 10 + 1) % m               [if n is odd]
```

You still need to be able to compute 10^n % m efficiently, and while this can be done using exponentiation by squaring, one can also use the fact that 10^n = 9*S(n)+1.

Using this latter relation between 10^n and S(n), one gets to this set of equations which are easily coded up as a recursive (or iterative) program:

```
S(n) % m =
   1                                 [if n is 1]
   x*(9x+2) % m where x = S(n/2)%m   [if n is even]
   ((S(n-1) % m) * 10 + 1) % m       [if n is odd]
```

In Python this gives a run-time for n=10^16, m=10^9 of 0.017s on my laptop, which is well within the 4s deadline.

Comment: Thank you very much.it really helps. Can i use Dynamic programming here to reduce the duplicate recursive call..

Comment: As long as in the even case you write "long x=S(n/2)%m; return x*(9*x+2) % m;` rather than `return S(n/2)*(9*S(n/2)+2) % m;` there are no duplicate recursive calls.

Answer (score 1):

I have a thought that might help you in some way optimising your code.

The following is my direct translation of my maths notes (with comments in italic font), so if you find something unclear, please point it out.

How to find if number is divisible by 37 *(in your case it is m)*

We have following

10^0 ≡ 1 (mod 37)
10^1 ≡ 10 (mod 37)
10^2 ≡ 26 (mod 37)
10^3 ≡ 1 (mod 37)

*basically do this until you see repetition*

So now if we want to see if number is divisible by 37 (or what is leftover) we substitute the powers of 10 with coefficients we got above. This means that 
a*10^3 + b*10^2 + c*10^1 + d mod 37 **=** a*1 + b*26 + c*10 + d mod 37.

An example with real number

(a number with 10^16 digits `1`) mod 37 = (1 + 26 + 10 + 1) * 10^16 / 4 mod 37 = 21

*you can repeat this process more then once, every time you do this the resultant number is shrinking proportionally (number with 10^16 digits shrank to a number with 16 digits)*

Comment: Shouldn't you be dividing 10^16 by 3 (since 10^3=1 mod 37), and then dealing with the remainder? I think this gives the correct answer of 1, not 21.

Comment: @Anonymus Yes it should. Your answer is way more efficient though. (and the reason for that with bigger m chances are that you will never get the repetition, which instantly ruins everything)

Comment: @Arvy The sequence will always either return to 1 or to 0 depending whether 10 is coprime (or not) to m, so your method always works.